# How to get current time hours using only JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

How do I get the current time using only JSP? I have no control over the bean, but I want to use the current time ( specifically the hours in 24 hour format ) for a comparison.

I have a bean with a time

```
 ${Qlist.beginTime} <---- e.g. 1440 ( 14:40 )
```

and I would like to check if the current time is greater than that.

Something like this, except I need the current time :

```
  <c:set var="currentTimein24Format" value="1441"/>
  <c:if test="${Qlist.beginTime<currentTimein24Format}">
      Currently running!
  </c:if>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have to use `<fmt:formatDate>`.

```
<jsp:useBean id="date" class="java.util.Date"/>

<fmt:formatDate var="time"  
                value="${date}"
                pattern="HHmm"/>
<br/>${time}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that kind of logic in JSP. It's better to do this in your bean:

```
public boolean isRunning(){
  return this.beginTimeInt < currentTimeInt;
}
```

So you can use it like this in JSP:

```
<c:if test="${myBean.running}">
  It's running!
</c:if>
```

Why is this better? Let's say you need more requirements for you bean to be running, for example it needs to be approved and it has an end time. Then you would need to add conditions everywhere in your JSP's where you check if your bean is running, whilst this would mean just a simple change if you would have the logic in your bean. So, you're less flexible and your JSP's will become less readable.